# Grouping Events in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

With a table that looks something like this:

```
id  name    DATE
1   a   2020-01-01
2   a   2020-01-02
3   b   2020-01-03
4   b   2020-01-04
5   a   2020-01-05
6   b   2020-01-06
```

I'd like to group pairs of `a` with the next (ordered by time) `b` so I can find the difference in their dates. Ideally this would look like:

```
id_a    id_b    difference
1       3       2
2       4       2
5       6       1
```

This seems tricky ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8e02b5/8)) with an `inner join` since selecting against the same table with something like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
INNER JOIN test AS t2 ON test.name = "a"
AND t2.name = "b"
AND test.date < t2.date;
```

ends up matching more than 1 `a` with each later `b`, and filtering this seems difficult since `1` needs to match with `3` and `2` with `4`, so a simple rule like the smallest difference doesn't work. Is something like this even possible with MySQL (8.0)?

Comment: I would rank a and b records separately then join on the rank and calcukate the date diff. Ranking depends on the version of mysql, but there are tons of examples here on SO for all versions.

Comment: Difference between start dates of two names?

Comment: What if according `b` have earlier date than according `a`? negative difference? What if the amount of `a` is greater than the amount of `b`?